# in expression engine 2.2.2; my css doesn't work everywhere, why?

Tags: php, javascript, expressionengine

I am a beginner in programming and in the use of expressionengine, I don't understand why my CSS desn't work, I explain:

-in first, I intented to make a template for it, in html tags, but unsuccessfully

-in second, I intented to make it with a snippet, with the same method, unsuccessfully too

-at least, I did it whith a snippet but with a css's file's link, and it work but only with my index's template's group

thank you for answer to a noob in programming

Best wishes, seb.

Thank you for having answered,

of course I can, this is what is there in my snippet "header":

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Metamorphosis Design Free Css Templates</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
</head>
<body>
```

thank you for the time you passe on my request, thanks à lot.

yes, it work, thank you very much florian^^^^.

---

the relative path was wrong because the road was not where it was,

I used the first way FortySeven Media, it lacked a level of the tree

thanks a lot for all every body

Comment: "doesn't work" --> In what way? "everywhere" --> Where? Browsers? Server environment? Also, where's the relevant code?

Comment: Seb,
If you were able to provide some links or snippets of the code you're using, we'll be better placed to help ;-)

Comment: @Rob W: Look attentively at this post and you'll know how I did it, for the environment, it's on a local server for the moment (apache server), where? it passed on each page, browser? I use firefox

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a linking issue. make sure your path to the url file works from all templates..

I usually do something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{site_url}css/style.css?v=2">
```

Then I create a folder on the ftp called 'css' and I upload my css file there.

You could put the  line into to a snippet and include that with all your templates ..

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you're [linking to stylesheets](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/stylesheet.html) correctly in your templates.

If your CSS is an ExpressionEngine template:

```
<link href="{stylesheet=template_group/template_name}" media="all" />
```

If your CSS is a file on your server:

```
<link href="{path=/css/screen.css}" media="all" />
```

If your CSS is a [Snippet](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/snippets.html) or [Global Variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/user_defined.html):

```
<link href="{snippet_name}" media="all" />
```

Which method you choose is up to you, though each approach has advantages and disadvantages *(which are out of the scope for this discussion)*.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that without telling it specifically where to look it will try to look in the current directory. So if you were at site.com/page it would be looking in the page directory for the CSS file.

Like florian said, either using

```
{site_url}css/style.css?v=2
```

or just adding a slash at the front should make it always look to the root first.

```
/css/style.css?v=2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be it, but a common issue: When you create a template in EE, EE serves that template using the exact name you set, with no file extension.

So, if you created css/style, but you're referencing css/style.css, you'll run into problems. Make sure that your template name includes the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

in fact, I used an extension file as you said Doug with the syntax wich florian gave me and now it works very well

thanks a lot everybody